# How do you show a custom action when publishing a custom story in facebook open graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

[image]

I would like to add a custom action to my facebook open graph story like 'save this recipe' in the picture above. I have already created the necessary custom actions, objects and story. I just can't find how I need to post my story to show these custom actions.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I can’t locate that in the Open Graph documentation any more right now. But I know it was previously possible for normal posts as well – isn’t any more, but how it was done is still described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user/feed#publish – the `actions` parameter takes a name and URL, and IIRC for OG stories it works the same. (Or at least used to; if it is not officially documented any more, they might have removed it completely.)

Comment: We've deprecated these Open Graph "Action Links" so it isn't supported anymore.